# Importing function from program in a subdirectory

Tags: python, import

Using python I launch a script from a certain point. From here, there's the subdirectory "A" where it's contained the file "B.py", which contains a class called "C"

```
from A import C
```

Traceback
ImportError: cannot import name 'C' from 'A' (unknown location). Is there an easy way to make python look in A then in B and finally get C? Thank you

Comment: Did you mean: `from A.B import C`?

Comment: Moreover, the subdirectory "A" should contain an empty file `__init__.py`

Comment: I have already tried to write 
`from A.B import C` 
and put the `__init__.py` empy file inside my directory A. It keeps giving a traceback (ImportError: cannot import name 'C' from 'A')

Answer (score 1):

If I have a directory structure like the following:

```
A -----------|
             |- B.py

test.py
```

`B.py` contains the following code:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        print("I made it to C!")
```

If I'm writing `test.py` to need an instance of `C` I need to import like this:

```
from A.B import C

myInst = C()
```

And I get the following output when I run `test.py`

```
I made it to C!
```

Alternatively, you can add the path to the directory containing `B.py` to your `PATH` with the `sys` module. To show this, I have put the file `E.py` in the structure of `A/B/C/D/E.py` along with an empty file named `__init__.py`

[image]
'=

`E.py` contains the following code:

```
class F:
    def __init__(self):
        print("I made it to C!")
```

`test.py` contains the following code:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "./A/B/C/D/") # You can put the absolute path

from E import F

myInst = F()
```

And I get the output:

```
I made it to C!
```

Comment: By writing `from A.B import C` I still get a traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
from A import C
ImportError: cannot import name 'C' from 'A' (unknown location)

Comment: @NicolòRaffuzzi I see that in above comments, you already have put a `__init__.py` file in the `A` directory. Is this truly the structure of your directory then? Is there any more nesting? Have you spelled the names of your directories right?

If the structure is not the exact same, this will not work. You may need to add the path to `B.py` to your PATH variable and then you can simply `from B import C`

Comment: @NicolòRaffuzzi I edited the post for something else that you can try

Comment: Thank you all for your help, nothing of what you suggested was wrong. I just realized that the modified version of cosmoMC (the monte carlo paramenter sampling code for cosmology) that I was using was missing a lot of files, so that when it comes to import those utilities they weren't found.
Thank you anyway for your support.

Comment: Thanks for this guide. I got that from your answer within many Q/As.